# How to run an SSIS program in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, ssis

I am trying to run an SSIS program inside of my C# program (alternatively I would be happy to do it the other way if someone knows a tutorial or reference on how to do this). I have followed this tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/658959/Execute-SSIS-Packge-by-using-Csharp-and-SQL-Server but keep getting the errors:

Error   2   Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSPackage100' to 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.Package'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)   P:\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SmartSheetAPI\SmartSheetAPI\SIIS.cs

Error   3   No overload for method 'LoadPackage' takes 2 arguments

The last one is interesting because in the example he only uses two parameters?

Can anyone help?

```
public class SIIS
{
    string pkg = @"P:\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Smartsheet Conversion\Smartsheet Conversion\Smartsheet.dtsx";

    public SIIS()
    {

    }

    public void test()
    {
        Application app = new Application();
        Package p = app.LoadPackage(pkg, false, null);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example on starting packages with C#:
http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2012/09/call-ssis-2012-package-within-net.html

Comment: Thanks that was helpful. Still not sure what I was doing wrong though.